# Passagem de um vetor para uma função em C

Tags: c, array, funções

Em minhas práticas em C, resolvi praticar a utilização de um vetor através de uma função, utilizando o método de passagem por parâmetro. O objetivo do programa é de receber os 5 elementos de um vetor, em seguida, mostrar o vetor através de uma função (show). Porém, após a leitura dos 5 valores, simplesmente mais nada acontece, aparecendo a mensagem de erro **Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)**. Qual a melhor forma de corrigir o código? Desde já obrigado!

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void show(int v[5]);
void main()
{
    int vet[5],i;
    printf("Digite 5 numeros:");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        scanf("%d",&vet[5]);
    show(vet[5]);
}
void show(int v[5])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("%d",v[5]);
}
```

Comment: Aqui: show(vet[5]); você está passando sexto elemento do vetor, aquele com índice 5 (apesar de seu vetor só ter espaço para 5 elementos, com índices de 0 a 4), e não o vetor. Utilize: show(vet);.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, então... você está cometendo uns erros básicos de C.
Primeiramente, você deve passar o vetor sem indexá-lo. Assim:

```
show(vet);
```

Além disso, nos seus laços, aí sim você deve indexar o vetor. Assim:

```
printf("%d",v[i]);
scanf("%d"&vet[i]);
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Corrigindo o uso incorreto de índices e tornando sua função show mais geral:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void show(int[], int);
int main()
{
    int vet[5],i;
    printf("Digite 5 numeros:");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        scanf("%d", &vet[i]);
    show(vet, 5);
    return 0;
}
void show(int v[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d", v[i]);
}
```

Comment: "show(vet[], 5);" isso não compila...

Comment: Como já havia dito no comentário: utilize show(vet, 5);. Faltou apagar o desnecessário. corrigido.